# Container for package manager in local development with docker?

Tags: linux, docker, composer-php

If my local system is linux, I can run composer, npm, phpunit etc localy. 
Is it a good practice still to create container for each of them in my docker-compose.yaml?

Comment: Can you give an example of how and why you might do this?  I'd tend to run these not-in-Docker doing actual development, and in my Dockerfile while building an image, but it's hard for me to imagine a use case for a container to just run an nom command.

Comment: ```docker run --rm --interactive --tty \
  --volume $PWD:/app \
  composer install ```

Comment: `composer install` without any of the Docker stuff is literally a quarter the length, doesn't require root-equivalent privileges, avoids potential confusion around file ownership, and doesn't potentially encode an incorrect absolute path anywhere; plus it will work on any system that's set up to do PHP development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using docker for local development but don't intend to use it on production then it kind of depends on your own preferences. It can be quite nice to not have any of the node/composer or whatnot tools installed on your local machine and simply use `docker run -it --rm -v $PWD:/app composer install` for example.

But - if you are developing in a team then I would suggest you have a common docker image so that all developers would have exactly the same environment while developing and running those commands (versions etc...)